# URLSession dataTaskPublisher with retry as MJPEG stream

Tags: swift, combine

I am trying to use the `URLSession.dataTaskPublisher` to create a retrying Publisher, which connects to a MJPEG stream.

Unfortunately my Subscriber never really receives any data, although I can see that data is transferred and the RAM consumption slowly increases. So the stream is open and data is received but not on the Subscriber. I had a version which received data once, but then closed the stream immediately.

I have tried many different configurations but the following seems to be closest to the goal:

What am I missing? Has someone encountered this kind of memory leak before?

I am mostly interested in a `timeout` error but also want to retry when something else is not working properly.

```swift
var cancellables: Set<AnyCancellable> = []
let url = URL(string: "http://mjpeg.stream")!
let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.ephemeral
configuration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 1
configuration.requestCachePolicy = .reloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData
let datataskpublisher = URLSession(configuration: configuration)
    .dataTaskPublisher(for: url)

let catcher = datataskpublisher
    .tryCatch { (error) -> AnyPublisher<(data: Data, response: URLResponse), URLError> in
        print("ERROR: \(error.code)")
        throw error
    }.eraseToAnyPublisher()

let retryer = catcher
    .catch { (error) -> AnyPublisher<(data: Data, response: URLResponse), Error> in
        print("RETRYING")
        return catcher.delay(for: 0.5, scheduler: DispatchQueue.global()).eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
    .eraseToAnyPublisher()


retryer
    .sink(receiveCompletion: { result in
          print("COMPLETED")
          switch result {
          case .failure(let fail):
               print("FAIL \(fail)")
          case .finished:
               print("FINISHED")
          }
     }, receiveValue: { value, response in
          print("DATA")
          let data = value
                    // parsing data
    })
    .store(in: &self.cancellables)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`URLSession.DataTaskPublisher` isn't suitable for this purpose. It will only emit at most one output. You can look at [its implementation](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/Darwin/Foundation/Publishers%2BURLSession.swift) to understand why: it creates a `URLSessionDataTask` with a completion handler. The task only calls the completion handler once, when it has received the complete response.

If you want to receive the data as it arrives, you need to create an object that conforms to [`URLSessionDataDelegate`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlsessiondatadelegate) and use that object as the delegate of your `URLSession`. Apple doesn't provide a `Publisher` that does this. If you want a `Publisher` that provides data incrementally, you'll have to write it yourself.

Comment: I have implemented it with URLSessionDelegate, I just wanted to use the more "modern"  dataTaskPublisher. Thanks for the info! Although I am still curious why I can see that the Network is receiving data via the debug session view in Xcode and I am not receiving it on any end.